# What does being completely encased in rock feel like after a few hours?

Tags: biology, temperature

The stone magician has defeated several crooks, and lacking handcuffs he simply encases them in individual round boulders which can then be rolled to the appropriate destination. What does that feel like for the crooks?

My specific concern is heat. If we have people ranging in height from 1.5 to 1.8 metres, and they're surrounded from head to toe in a perfect sphere of granite for hours, will they become too hot or too cold? Or will it balance out and they'll just be stiff? Stone generally feels cold to me, even if I sit on it for quite some time, but these poor sods are completely encased and have no efficient way to sweat.

The crook-boulders are stored at room temperature for 24 hours. Their faces are exposed, they have some spare room around the chest to breathe, and the stone is not so tight that bloodflow is constrained. They're wearing regular clothes underneath their granite straitjackets.

Comment: You could perhaps ask people who've been a full-body cast.

Comment: Frankly, I would be more concerned about the proposed rolling. Granite isn't rubber, and if there is the slightest room for movement, your prisoners will get bumped around and may end up with a concussion, if not broken bone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Wow, that would reek...**

- Heat stroke
- Nitrate burns (betcha they can't hold it for 24 hours)
- Serious cramps (the body actually hates immobility, and the weight is still on the feet... unless it's on the crotch...)
- Oh, the smell...
- Make sure the stone is far enough below their mouths that the sweat (and other nastiness...) has somewhere to go, or they'll drown.
- Hearing deprivation... not good...

[Obligatory music video expressing basic nature of anyone who would do this to another person... :-)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsUXAEzaC3Q)

Comment: Hearing deprivation? :O Also, is the heat stroke just because they cannot effectively sweat? I was considering that being in semi-direct (through clothes) contact with the rock would allow them to conduct (if that's a verb) off their excess heat, perhaps even more effectively than through sweating.

Comment: I'm assuming the rock doesn't cover their faces, but covers everything else. By the end of 24 hours the only thing they'd be able to hear is their own heartbeat (think "Chinese water torture"). And, no, the rock wouldn't wick away nearly enough heat. Rock's actually a pretty good insulator. So, yeah, you'd feel the heat in minutes.

Comment: Well then... this just got a lot more torturous than I had expected :O

Comment: On a second thought, I should have realised that rock would be a good insulator - a rock shell around a heat source is basically what a stone oven is, and they keep heat in pretty well!

Comment: Heat Stroke: The insulation factor per inch (R value) of granite varies from (R = .038 to .083), nearly two orders of magnitude below the value of, for example, a winter coat (R = 3 or 4).

Comment: I'd have gone with another song: "sociopath" by stelouse.